# Sticky toolbar doesnt work after adding sideNav to the project

Tags: html, css, angular

In my project I was using sticky material toolbar.After added sidenav-bar.That `position:sticky` doesn't work.That toolbar turned into normal one which doesn't come with you when you scroll the page.I checked all other possible solutions on Google but didn't work for me.Could you help me please?

**App.Component.Html**

```
    <div [@routeAnimations]="o && o.activatedRouteData 
            && o.activatedRouteData['animation']"> 
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav role="navigation"  position="end">
<app-sidenav-list (closeSidenav)="sidenav.close()"></app-sidenav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content>
            <navbar (sidenavToggle)="sidenav.toggle()"></navbar>
            <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>

</mat-sidenav-content>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**App-Component.Css**

```
mat-sidenav-container,mat-sidenav-content,mat-sidenav{
    height:100%;
}

mat-sidenav{
    width:200px;
}
```

**Css for Mat-Toolbar**

```
mat-toolbar {
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
body {
  padding: 3%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25vh;
  min-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 5%;
}

.main {
  width: 60%;
  height: 200vh;
  min-height: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main,
.sidebar {
  border: 5px solid #222;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #222;
  padding: 15px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

code,
pre {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 0 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.bottom {
  justify-self: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
    <h2>Main content</h2>
    <p>Scroll down the page!</p>
    <h3>How to recreate this</h3>
    <p>Position the columns with flex. Then apply two lines of CSS to the sidebar to make it sticky:</p>
    <pre>Include</pre>
    <code>position: -webkit-sticky;</code>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <h3>Sticky sidebar</h3>
    <p>I will follow you!</p>
    <p><a href="#">caniuse stats</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```